# Is there any ring in which union of proper ideals is the whole ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Last class we were discussing the proof (using Zorn's lemma) that every commutative ring with unity has a maximal ideal. 
In the proof, we strongly use the fact that every proper ideal must not contain $1$, and so any union of these proper ideals must remain proper, after all this union must not contain $1$.

So my question is: is it possible to proof the same result without assuming the unity element? The argument with $1$ seems crucial to ensure the union is proper. Is there any ring (of course, without $1$) in which union of finite ideals is the whole ring?

Comment: The union of a *chain* of proper ideals is proper. The union of arbitrary sets of ideals is not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Notice also that, if you have a rng $R$ without identity but which nevertheless is Noetherian, (meaning it satisfies the ACC on ideals) you can still conclude that the union of an ascending chain of proper ideals has a maximal element, so that its union is equal to the maximal element, and hence is proper. That leads us to consider only rngs which lack the ACC on ideals.

---

Take any non-Noetherian ring $R$ with identity and find a strictly increasing chain of ideals $I_0\subset I_1\subset I_2\subset\ldots$.

Then $I=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$ is an ideal of $R$ which is not equal to any of the $I_j$.

Since $I_j\lhd R$, $I_j\lhd I$ as a ring without identity.

By construction, $I$ is a union of a chain of proper ideals of $I$.

Concretely, you could take the union of the chain $(x_1)\subset (x_1,x_2)\subset (x_1, x_2, x_3)\subset\ldots$ in $K[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$ (in countably many variables.)